# In Scrapy, download files nested below the to of a yielded item dict

Tags: scrapy

To download files in Scrapy, one adds the key 'fileurls' to the yielded item dict with a value of the urls to download. But my files are nested somewhere below the top level of the yielded dict. An item looks like this:

```
{
  "title": "foo",
  "files": {
    "drawings": [
      {
        "caption": "bar",
        "fileurl": "http://foo.com/foo/foo.pdf"
      },
      {
        "caption": "second floor",
        "fileurl": "http://foo.com/foo/bar.pdf"
      }
    ],
    "photos": [
      {
        "caption": "bar",
        "fileurl": "http://foo.com/foo/baz.pdf"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like each file downloaded and have scrapy add its "file" element next to the "fileurl". But this does not seem to work automatically.

How can I achieve this? The current version of Scrapy is 1.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do something like this, you will need to make your own subclass of scrapy's [`FilesPipeline`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline).

To make the downloading happen, you'll need a custom `get_media_requests` method, which should get the URLs from your item and return an iterable of requests which will be used to download the files.

After that, you'll also need to modify the `item_completed` and/or the `file_downloaded` method to store the result in the exact way you want.

If you need more details than what's provided in the docs, take a look at [the source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L443) and see how the existing pipeline works.

Comment: Thanks. I'll skip this for now and do what I need in a postprocessing step.